# Swift struct type recursion

Tags: swift, recursion, struct

Why can't structs have recursive value types in Swift? 
Is this a temporary limit of the language or is it as intended?

I feel that the ability to declare a binary tree node as a struct with recursive types in it to be the most natural implementation.

```
struct TreeNode<E>{
var leftNode:TreeNode<E>
var rightNode:TreeNode<E>
var element:E
}
```

Comment: You need to understand the difference between a reference type and a value type first. What you wrote is impossible in most languages. For example, in C/Obj-C/C++ the `leftNode` and `rightNode` would have to be pointers. In Swift, if you want to use references, you should use `class` instead of `struct`. Also note that you will probably want optionals.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The answer is in your question: structs are value types. If you include a substruct `B` into a struct `A`, it means, that one object of type `A` will have a size `sizeof(all_other_fields_of_A) + sizeof(B)`. So, a value type can not be recursive: it would have infinite size.

Comment: Just for future reference: the key is understanding what value types are as explained by @Sulthan .

Answer (score 8):

Enums in Swift support recursive types using the `indirect` keyword so you can do something like:

```
indirect enum Tree<T> {

    case Node(left: Tree?, right: Tree?, element: T)

}
```

Check out this great blog post [A persistent tree using indirect enums in Swift](http://airspeedvelocity.net/2015/07/22/a-persistent-tree-using-indirect-enums-in-swift/)

Comment: I'm aware of this method but its persistence is something I want to avoid.