# Compiler error because of recursive function calling in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to build a simple design system for my pet project to share between android and iOS apps.
The definitions of widgets are in the common Kotlin module.
I am trying to write swift UI functions to build actual views:

```swift
@ViewBuilder
    func widget(widget: MyWidget) -> some View {
        switch widget {
        case let box1 as MyBox:
            box(box: box1)
        default:
            fatalError("Unsupported widget: \(widget)")
        }
    }
```

```swift
@ViewBuilder
    func box(box: MyBox) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(box.children) { child in
                widget(widget: child)
            }
        }
    }
```

When compiling the project, I get the following error:

> Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code

Removing the recursion (like replacing `widget` call with a `Text`) resolves the compilation problem.

Note that these functions are not called anywhere else.

XCode version 14.1

- Removing recursive call fixes compiler error

Comment: Box calls widget and widget calls box. You can't do that with Swift structs.

Comment: yeah, recursion is there intentionally. works beautifully with compose impl
can you please provide a link to swift ui doc that explains this limitation?

Comment: Just a fact of life in Swift, structs can't recurse.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift struct type recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36080491/swift-struct-type-recursion)

Comment: The only issue with recursion and structure is when a struct stores itself. There’s no mention of storing these in fields here, just calling functions in a mutually recursive way. what’s the issue here?

Comment: SwiftUI views are struct : the compiler try to build the view tree with your view builder function which leads to struct recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Structs in Swift must have a size that is knowable at compilation. In other words, a struct cannot contain a variably-sized object. A struct *can* contain an array or string or other variably-sized object by using a constant-sized reference to said object (a pointer, essentially). You *can't* do this:

```swift
struct A {
  var b: B
}

struct B {
  var a: A
}
```

But you *can* do this, because both `_a` and `_b` are actually just pointers to arrays (i.e, constant size regardless of size of the array or the objects in the array), and `A.b` and `B.a` are *computed properties* that are not actually stored.

```swift
struct A {
  var _b: [B]

  var b: B {
    get {
      return _b[0]
    }
    set(new) {
      _b[0] = new
    }
  }
}

struct B {
  var _a: [A]

  var a: A? {
    get {
      return _a[0]
    }
    set(new) {
      _a[0] = new
    }
  }
}
```

And you can also do this, because storing a `Box<T>` value only stores a pointer to a `Box<T>` object, so the size of the reference does not depend on the size of the referenced value.

```swift
class Box<T> {
  var value: T

  init(value: T) {
    self.value = value
  }
}

struct A {
  var b: Box<B>
}

struct B {
  var a: Box<A>
}
```

Since SwiftUI views are structs, they *cannot* be recursive.  There are multiple ways of creating recursive data structures in Swift, and I don't know enough about SwiftUI to say what approach is appropriate in your use case. You can box stuff in via a wrapper class or wrapping in an array, or you can create a recursive Enum box object via the `indirect` keyword:

```swift
enum Maybe<T> {
  case None
  indirect case Some(_ value: T)
}

struct A {
  var b: Maybe<B>
}

struct B {
  var a: Maybe<A>
}


let foo = A(b: .None)
let bar = B(a: .Some(A(b: .None)))
```